# Key error when selecting columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i wanna sum the price for every psychic_id
and i always get the same error  keyerror : id

```
df2=pd.DataFrame(df_consultation,columns= ['id', 'psychic_id','start','end','duration','price','satisfaction','created_at','updated_at','duration_available'])

df2= df2.fillna(0)
```

```py
for i in df2 : 

    if df2['psychic_id'][i]== df2['psychic_id'][i + 1]:

        tot_gain = df2.get['price'] [i] + df2.get['price'] [i + 1]

df2['tot_gain_€'] = tot_gain
```

Comment: what is `df_consultation`?

Comment: it s the call in general  but in french sryy

Comment: I meant, what is the content of the object? Your code is not reproducible

Comment: what object didn t get it sryy  i m newbie

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. the current issue is that `for i in df2:` is not row iteration. it will iterate over column names. try `print(i)` in the for loop to see. However, `for-loop` in general is an anti pattern of pandas and what you are trying to do is perhaps either `df2.price.sum()` or `df2.groupby('psychic_id').sum()`.  ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html

also I would recommend looking up "vectorization" in pandas.